# Which shortcut to complete current line with `;` then start a new line?

Tags: c#, intellij-idea, rider

In Visual Studio (with Resharper), I can do that with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It helps me to finish current line with `;`, which is very helpful, I don't need to navigate to the end of the line to insert `;`

In Rider, according to my current Keymap, there is a [Start New Line]:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a new line, but without this feature.

Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

See the shortcut for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap | All Actions | Editor Actions | **Complete Current Statement** [action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html).